# RDLC 2005 conversion to RDLC 2008 : Custom code not "seen" anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, rdlc

I have some issues with my reports since I have updated them to VS2010 format.

Even though I have modified references to from v9 to 10 for Microsoft.ReportViwer.Common and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms as well, when I try to type code. in a field, what is after "Code." is always underlined with red and I get #ERROR instead of the value I want when I print the report. I know it is case sensitive and I double checked the spelling multiple times.

Moreover, I don't know why but I have errors with the Fields! syntax; I seem to have to use the Fields().value to get them to work (at the places I don't need to call custom code too)

These reports worked well before conversion (over 20 reports converted this way) but do not now. Seems like custom functions are not "seen" by the report designer. I tryed to make them public, shared; all I had is the same stupid #ERROR display.

I want them to work in VS2010 to avoid always having to modify them in VS2008 and then go back in VS2010

It's a winform application with framework 3.5

Any idea of what could cause that and what is the remedy?

Many thanks

Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to use custom code in SSRS. Firstly you can enter VB directly into the window under 
Report -- >Report Properties --> Code

Another way is to write a custom DLL (which can be done in any .NET language of course), which then needs to be copied to both your dev machine and the production report server. 
You then need to create references to that assembly in the project using:
Report --> Report Properties --> References  (I assume you know this).

If you are not using your own custom assembly, and just using a reference to one on your machine then there could be some confusion on the server as to where to find the dll's. You may need to copy DLL's to the folder as indicated in the KB link below:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920769

When you drag a field onto a tablix or textbox, and have a look at the value expression, does it use the Fields!Fieldname.Value syntax? That syntax is natural to SSRS so it sounds like something seriously broken in your visual studio 2010 there if that is not working. I take it you installed visual studio 2010 to create web applications. What you haven't explained is which version of BIDS or SSDT you are using. If you are developing reports for SSRS 2008 R2 or earlier, then these are not compatible with visual studio 2010. There's no compromise there.

If you are developing for SSRS 2012, then you are using either SSDT by itself (which installs a shell version of visual studio 2010) OR if you already have visual studio 2010 then you need to install service pack 1 for VS2010 and then install SSDT from the SQL Server 2012 disc.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500335(v=vs.103).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500335%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)